# Combining errors from multiple regressions

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, standard-error, uncertainty

I have the following problem:

- I need to find out the efficiency of a system.

what I have done:

- I modelled a set of random scenarios of this system.
- I managed to make out trends in the data and fit regressions through them

So at the moment I have, from known model results:

$Efficiency  = temperature * a + pressure * b + cst$

I also have relationships which allow me to find the value of pressure  from depth, also using known model results:

$pressure = depth * c + cst$

Okay so my question is now:

Say I want to find out the efficiency for a value of pressure which I haven't modelled. I can do so by determining pressure from my known relationship to depth. In fact, the database I have only has detph values.

So my problem is that if for the efficiency regression I found a standard error of 1.3 and for the pressure regression a standard error of 10.5, by how much will my efficiency regression worsen when I derive my pressure using the regression rather than modelled values ?

NOTE: The regressions I have are more complex than the ones given here but the same principle should apply